# htaccess rewrite rule enrute 2 times

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I have a big problem with .htaccess rewrite rule, my code is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If i set a in index.php this:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
$bufer = ob_get_flush();
file_put_contents('publico'.microtime().'.txt',$bufer);
die();
```

And enter in my domain ONE TIME http://myweb.test, two files are created in the directory..

EDIT: More info, into the files like "publico0.21721500 1314986273.txt", the FIRST file have a "array()" string, the SECOND file have a "Array([url] => favicon.ico)" string ??¿

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: No need for the edit ;) I'm pretty sure I nailed it already hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) is request automatically. So that is your second request.

If you add a favicon to your document root, then you shouldn't have that issue. You can also confirm that this is the problem by checking your Apache access logs.

Comment: YES! is correct, if i put the favicon.ico in the directory, only one file is saved.. ¿For WHAT? ¿bug? i dont understand how the server send a request for this file ¿its possible to disable?

Comment: No problem. +1 for me?  I'm 15 points away from hitting my 200 daily limit so i'm happy to be seen begging.

Comment: +1 Nice catch.  @Zenth No -- that's how browsers work. Better add an exclusion to your rewrite rule to ignore requests for `favicon.ico`

Comment: @Layke You hit over 300 rep 2 days ago -- do you need another 200+ day?

Comment: @LazyOne he shouldn't need to add an ignore. If my memory serves me correctly, based on his rules, if he adds the file, it will be sufficient.

Comment: @LazyOne lol. I decided to go for the Legendary Badge at 150 days of 200+ reputation.

Comment: @Layke Yes .. but what if he does not want to add it? It's much better and more importantly **safer** to add exclusion.

Comment: 2 Minutes left to +1 for you ;)
and realy thanks for th help, im losing about 40 minutes debuging ALL files in a CMS..
PD The rule for omit favicon.ico ?

Comment: Zenth : You don't need a rule to omit, just add the file and that should take care of it. If it doesn't then I'm wrong, but from what I remember, !-d and !-f will match if file not exists...

Comment: Thanks!!!!
Err.. I press +1 but message appears: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation", lol.. sorry :S